# How to shoot in-situ product videos in restricted locations?

Tags: video, premiere, video-recording, filming, render

This question is location based, and hoping to get some ideas at the very least.  I work for a company that manufactures products for the construction industry, such as secure storage units, tool chests, manual handling products such as sack trucks, etc - you get the idea.

I want to start shooting product video, but for maximum effect I think they really need to be in situ - ie, shot on a construction site, however such sites, especially in the UK are restricted, and only authorised personnel are allowed on site.

With this in mind, what is the best way to shoot the video I want?  Do I try and contact construction sites near me and get them to allow me on site (bearing in mind that construction sites are only suitable for filming for a few months - our products wouldn't get used very early in the construction stage, and they also wouldn't be used nearer the end fitout stage).  Would it be simpler and cheaper long term to build a film set?  I'm thinking that CGI is likely to be too costly to be viable?  Are there any other options?

Really appreciate any experience or ideas that can be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people apart from construction workers need to visit building sites, so there are processes for that to safely happen. I used to have a job where we often shot in restricted locations like building sites and factories. It usually involved the producer contacting whoever controlled the site and asking permission, and then we usually had to go through the site induction process (so many induction videos, so, so many).

A few things to note: when you're on site be aware that you will probably wear out your welcome–most people don't realise how long it takes to shoot a video, they expect you to turn up, wave the camera around and go. So it's worth being clear to whoever is going to accompany you on site about how long you think the shoot will take.

Also be aware that the camera operator needs to have support people. If they're in a location like a building site there are lots of dangers around, and if they're focussed on the camera, they may not be fully aware of their surroundings. At the same time, you want to keep the crew to a minimum, so you don't have unnecessary stragglers wandering around.